# Show soft keyboard when Activity starts when no text field is present

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

I want to open soft keyboard while starting an activity.

The activity contains nothing as its element. I just need to open soft keyboard on the launch.

I've tried with

`<activity android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysVisible|stateVisible|adjustResize"` but it didn't work.

Also tried with

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE);
```

but it didn't work as well

i'm using emulator to run the code

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried

```
<activity 
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustPan">
```

?

Answer (score 0):

HI,
you could try :

```
 InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.showSoftInput(flags, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
```

This will not open the keyboard if there is a physical one available and opened.(flags can be 0 if there is nothing.)

Answer (score 0):

try the below code hope it helps

```
<activity android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">
```

for more information regarding this [Read](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html)